# generate unique integer number to any user

Tags: flutter

I'm working in a project where users need to fill a report's form firstly by generating integer number of the report by clicking the button, that number should be incremented in sequence starting from 1. if user is filling the form of number 1 then button should generate 2 after that to any user who also will fill the form.... I've tried to do that as shown bellow but when I tried the app in different devices counter starts from 1 in each device, I mean there is no sequence in numbers, not quite sure but should I use shared preferences to hold the sequence of the number?

```
int _mainCounter = 0;
FToast fToast;

class Addshipment extends StatefulWidget {
  SharedPreferences prefs; //add
  @override
  _AddshipmentState createState() => _AddshipmentState();
}

class _AddshipmentState extends State<Addshipment> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {      
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: KInActiveColor,
        toolbarHeight: 120,
        title: Image.asset('',
            height: 100.0, alignment: Alignment.center),
      ),
      drawer: AppDrawer(),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: ListView(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
              child: CustomPaint(
                painter: MyPainter(),
                child: Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(25.0),
                  // color: KSecondaryColor,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                  child: Form(
                    key: _formKey,
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        ////////////////////////////// Button Generate random id
                        Container(
                          margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 0.5.h),
                          alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                          child: FlatButton(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(1.h),
                            child: Text(
                              'Generate unique number',
                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.sp, fontFamily: 'Cairo',),
                            ),
                            textColor: KWhiteColor,
                            color: KInActiveColor,
                            onPressed: () {
                              setState(() {                            
                                _counter = _mainCounter;
                                _counter++;
                                _controller.text = _counter.toString();
                                print(_counter);
                                Timer(Duration(seconds: 15), () { 
                              // if user didn't use number in 15 mins don't increment counter 
                              // and empty textField

                                  _counter--;
                                  _controller.text = '';
                                });

                                // }
                              });
                            },
                          ),
                        ),
```

here where to save form to firebase

```
 Container(

                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 3.h),
                      child: FlatButton(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(1.h),
                        child: Text(
                          'save', // to firebase
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.sp,fontFamily: 'Cairo'),
                        ),
                        textColor: KWhiteColor,
                        color: KInActiveColor,
                        onPressed: () {
                          if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {

                            if (_connectionStatus.toString() ==
                                'ConnectivityResult.none') {
                              _showToastNoConnectionToInternet();
                            } else {
                              uploadInfoToFirebase();
                               _mainCounter = _counter ;

                            }
                          }
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the best solution to your problem is rather than starting from 0 every time. You can write your method same as below...

```
onPressed: () {
   setState(() { 
      //Here rather than starting main counter every time with 0
      // you can get the last user id from database and do your following work                           
        _counter = //Get last user id from database;
        _counter++;
       ........do following code same you have
},
```

Comment: I did what you said as a first try, it worked just fine untill i found in database some docs having the same number... Then I started to think what if two users or more clicked the button at the same time that means they will all bring the same last number!!  Am i wrong with that logic?

Comment: If that is the case then you need to create id on the backend side.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't quite understand what u mean by creating id

Comment: let's join this chat room. I'll explain you
https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250562/generate-unique-integer-number-to-any-user